# expand tab is not working on vim

Tags: vim, vimrc

I set the `expandtab` option to on, but still I don't get spaces when I click tab, but I get actual tab.

This is how I set it:

```
set expandtab

set shiftwidth=4

set softtabstop=4
```

First I thought as [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/why-is-set-noexpandtab-in-my-vimrc-ignored-when-i-open-a-file) says that a plugin is override it, but I executed:

```
:verbose set expandtab?
```

and indeed I get that last set is the line in my vimrc

how can I solve it?

Comment: You don't seem to have an answer to this question, @JackThomson, and hopefully you've resolved it by now, but there's little information here to go on, and it can arise that you may deliberately or inadvertently `set paste` in addition to your `vimrc` settings. The `paste` setting also applies `noexpandtab`, and can cause this experience, but `expandtab`, if originally set, is restored once you `set nopaste`. Check `:set paste?`, it could be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can set it:
1. `$HOME/.vimrc`
2. inline inside the file

**.vimrc #1**
This is the settings I'm using:

```
"indent settings
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set nocompatible  " <= vim, not vi
```

And it works for me, also make sure you're using vim not vi (?) ..

**Inline #2**

inline settings for vi supported only when using `set modeline`
Meaning in your `$HOME/.vimrc` paste: `set modeline` and re-edit your file.